# How to make a relation to database tables(sql and phpmyadmin) such that it's unique for every record(PK)?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have 4 tables

1. student
2. college
3. degree
4. course

college and degree is connected to student

table course(subjects) is connected to degree // specific courses for each degree

I want a new table where I can save the student's grade such that every time a new record is created in the student table, a unique table for the student's grade(in relation to courses) is created.

I tried creating a field in the course table for it but every time I update a student's grade thru SQL commands, it looks to me that the grades are shared.

It's like "student(Many) -> course(Many) -> course_grade(1, shared)". 
Am I making sense?

I want the course_grade to be unique on every student. Is this achievable by just using phpmyadmin or do I need programming(PHP since this is web-based) intervention and create a table for each student record created?

How to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if I get your problem right, but you must absolutely not create a table for each student.

If you want to store each student's grade in each course, you have to create a relational table, its columns simply being: student, course, grade

That way, each time you want to save a student's grade, just make an INSERT into this table, using its ID, the course ID, and the grade (int, enum or whatever).

Make a SELECT in this table in order to get a student's grades. Join the "student" table to get their name, etc.

***EDIT about primary/foreign keys:***

A **primary key** is the column which makes each entry "unique". 
For instance in table "student" you may have an "id" or "student_id" column, maybe with auto_increment, this should be your primary key (there can obviously be only one per table).

A **foreign key**, on the other hand, is a way to tell MySQL that two columns in two different tables represent the same thing. That is not mandatory though, but "just" good practice.
In your case, this new table should have a foreign keys :

1. student which references student.id (the primary key of table "student")
2. course which references course.id (the primary key of table "course")

Creating foreign keys is not required, but good (and common) practice. This way, MySQL will throw error if, for example, you try to save a row in your table with a student id that does not exist in table "student".

I advise you to read about the concepts of foreign keys, primary keys, indexes etc. Like W3school: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: I think you get it haha, I have a question though, should the student and course in the column be an index(foreign key) or should one of them be a primary key(let's say student = primary and course = foreign)? Does it even have any difference?

Comment: I edited my answer to elaborate on this. And please validate my answer if it helped you!

Comment: Ooh thanks for the explanation, that helped!

I have 1 last question, I can insert a student record now but I was expecting every time I insert a student record, I should also see some query results in the grades table but I see none. Why is this?

Comment: You have to make 2 requests. But actually I don't understand why you'd want to insert a grade for a new student (he shouldn't have any grade?); for me they are two different operations, so 2 requests seems logical. In fact with this solution you can add grades and courses whenever you want.

Comment: Nevermind that question, I'm sure it's linked now after checking the "insert" module in phpmyadmin since it has results but I have to manually do the insertion though. I wonder if I can do the insertion programmatically rather than doing this manually. If you have ideas, can you reply back here? and Thank you very much!!!! :D

Comment: Many languages have easy ways to interact with a MySQL database, the more common being PHP. Depending on you project you may want to use another language, but if it's web-based PHP is a good start I think (you'll need a web server supporting this of course). Tons of resources and tutorials on the internet ;) And by the way, you're welcome!